# Neighborhoods: Interior

Tags: general-topology, definition

The neighborhood filters satisfy:
$$\forall N\in\mathcal{N}(x):\qquad x\in N$$
$$\forall N\in\mathcal{N}(x)\exists M_0\in\mathcal{N}(x):\qquad N\in\mathcal{N}(m)\text{ for all }m\in M_0$$
Define the interior:
$$A^\circ:=\{z:A\in\mathcal{N}(z)\}$$
Prove that the interior is contained:
$$A^\circ\subseteq A$$
and that the interior is open:
$$A^\circ\in\mathcal{N}(z)\text{ for all }z\in A^\circ$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z\in A^{\large\circ}$.

By definition, that means $A\in \mathcal{N}(z)$.

By the first property of neighborhood systems $z\in A$. This proves the first statement.

By the second property of neighbourhood systems, there is a $C\in \mathcal{N}(z)$ such that $A\in\mathcal{N}(c)$ for all $c\in C$. That means $c\in A^{\large\circ}$ for all $c\in C$, hence $C\subset A^{\large\circ}$. Since $\mathcal{N}(z)$ is a filter, $C\in \mathcal{N}(z)$ and $C\subset A^{\large\circ}$ imply $A^{\large\circ} \in \mathcal{N}(z)$. This proves the second statement.

Comment: Yes I thought so already -ok- but why is $V$ open? My point is actually why we define $N\in\mathcal{N}(u)$ rather than $U\in\mathcal{N}(u)$. I mean certainly the latter implies the former but couldn't it happen that the former has no opens at all?

Comment: The point is that a neighbourhood of $x$ shall also be a neighbourhood of all points "close enough to $x$". Close enough means "for all $u$ in some neighbourhood $U$ of $x$", $\bigl(\exists U \in \mathcal{N}(x)\bigr)$. $V$ is - in the topology induced by the neighbourhood system - the interior of $N$. By the demanded property, if $y\in V$, then $N\in\mathcal{N}(y)$, so there is a $W\in \mathcal{N}(y)$ such that $N\in \mathcal{N}(w)$ for all $w\in W$. That means $W\subset V$, so $V\in \mathcal{N}(y)$. Since $y\in V$ was arbitrary, $V$ is a neighbourhood of all of its points.

Comment: Do you mind if I specify my question?? You can of course fit your answer if necessary...

Comment: That depends on how much it changes the question. Specifying is usually fine, but if it changes the question too much, it should be a new one. Probably I won't mind, but please ping when you're done.

Comment: Ok good - I'll ping you in a few minutes.

Comment: Got it. Can adjust your answer too - that would very nice.

Comment: Okay. First I will have to read the new question, though.

Comment: Adjusted, @Freeze_S. If anything is unclear, ask.

Comment: Okay I did just change $U$ into $C$ so people won't get the wrong impression that $U$ is open...

Comment: Btw thanks for the good answer...